# What can "Search in Files" locate?

Tags: apex, search

I thought "Search in Files" was doing a simple text search in all my Apex files until I saw the following.  The following string was found

> "sl.ScholarProg.Cluster_Assigned__c"

but the following string was

> "Cluster_Assigned__c"

**not** found in at least one file when searched via "Search in Files" and with the file in question open as the current file in Dev. Console.  "Cluster_Assigned__c" *was* found in other files which makes the whole situation even more confusing.

Note that the second string is a substring of the first.

Any thoughts on how to avoid the problem of "Search in Files" not finding things that are clearly present?

Comment: Your description of what was and was not found is a bit hard to follow.

Comment: I've added quotes to show these are both text string I have searched for using "Search in Files".  If the searching done by the Dev Console is straight text search, why does it not find a string that is a substring of the string it CAN find?